# How to remove a tuple from a list of tuples on variable condition

Tags: python

I have list of tuples that needs to stripped based on condition from separate variable.
When `AppEnv == 'non-production'` I want to remove entire `production` tuple. While when `AppEnv == 'production'`, only `production` must remain.

```
AppEnv = 'non-production'

creds = [ ('development','usr', 'pass'),
                ('test', 'usr', 'pass'),
                ('production', 'usr', 'pass')]


creds = [i for i in creds if i[0] != 'production' and AppEnv == 'non-production']
print(creds)
```

Comment: I would suggest you use a dictionary here instead of list of tupples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could use [xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or):

```
AppEnv = 'non-production'

creds = [ ('development','usr', 'pass'),
                ('test', 'usr', 'pass'),
                ('production', 'usr', 'pass')]


creds = [i for i in creds if (i[0] != 'production') ^ (AppEnv != 'non-production')]
print(creds)
```

**Output**

```
[('development', 'usr', 'pass'), ('test', 'usr', 'pass')]
```

Changing AppEnv to "production":

```
AppEnv = 'production'

creds = [ ('development','usr', 'pass'),
                ('test', 'usr', 'pass'),
                ('production', 'usr', 'pass')]


creds = [i for i in creds if (i[0] != 'production') ^ (AppEnv != 'non-production')]
print(creds)
```

**Output**

```
[('production', 'usr', 'pass')]
```

A bit more cumbersome, but more general is to do the following functional approach:

```
from operator import eq, ne
from functools import partial

env = 'production'
keep = False

predicate = partial(eq if keep else ne, env)

creds = [('development', 'usr', 'pass'), ('test', 'usr', 'pass'), ('production', 'usr', 'pass')]
creds = [cred for cred in creds if predicate(cred[0])]
print(creds)
```

Comment: ngl I would prefer a for loop here.

Comment: What does ngl stands for?

Comment: not gonna lie :-)

Comment: Woah, `^ (AppEnv != 'non` looks like triple negation. I'd much prefer [**no** negation](https://tio.run/##jY/LCgIxDEX3/Yq4SgsjCG5EmIULv2KoIDMVA5qGtjPg11frA7QuNMubc0@IXNLR83IlIec@uCFCCx1oHNzkTl7OjhM2OMaADaDsY0TTKKhGY3IxFeInKMEPY5/I8xdulVIHH2AjsuUJiKGi2fP8LVnf9RKIk@4ISpVK6/EGHUBTt7Awaz88BnagnyfKqpIaa/7TtrX2Fry89c6anK8), i.e., "use production tuples if and only if we're in production environment".

Answer (score 1):

Think about the cases you need to cover:

1. `AppEnv == 'non-production'`: You want all tuples where `i[0] != 'production'` (You have this in your code already)
2. `AppEnv == 'production'`: You want all tuples where `i[0] == 'production'`.

So add those conditions:

```
creds_filtered = [i for i in creds if
                      (AppEnv == 'non-production' and i[0] != 'production')
                   or (AppEnv == 'production' and i[0] == 'production')]
```

There's probably a simpler boolean logic you can use, but this is the most easy to understand.

With `AppEnv = 'non-production'`, this gives

```
[('development', 'usr', 'pass'), ('test', 'usr', 'pass')]
```

With `AppEnv = 'production'`, this gives:

```
[('production', 'usr', 'pass')]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can filter for it depending on `AppEnv`:

```
out = list(filter(lambda x: (x[0]=='production' if AppEnv == 'production' else x[0]!='production'), creds))
```

Output:

When `AppEnv = 'non-production'`, output:

```
[('development', 'usr', 'pass'), ('test', 'usr', 'pass')]
```

When `AppEnv = 'production'`, output:

```
[('production', 'usr', 'pass')]
```